# Combining elements from multiple lists in Python

Tags: python

Say I have some lists:

```
t = ['a','b']
x = ['x1','x2','x3','x4']
y = ['y1','y2','y3','y4']
```

I would like to combine elements from those lists above, so I would have a new list looks like this

```
new = ['ax1y1x2y2','bx3y3x4y4']
```

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Please show your efforts and format your strings correctly

Comment: Hi guys. I'm kind of new to programming and stack overflow. I'm not exactly sure what 's wrong with my string format.

Comment: Welcome to the community @user17758135. The ```'y4'``` value didn't have the ```'``` . Eitherway, you need to always provide whatever you were able to accomplish. Even if it was a for loop that didn't work, any code of a previous attempt is useful for us to tell you what went wrong on your solution and help you improve in your code.

Comment: If you have no idea how to do that you can investigate a bit further on how to compute the **Cartesian product** of a string. Which I think is what you might be looking for.

Comment: It looks like `t` is split between `x` and `y`. Is it always half the size? Otherwise, is one of the three lists always half the size of the other two? I think this question could use more detail.

Comment: oh thank you so much for your comments.  the number of elements of the t list is fixed. The numbers of elements of list x and lists y vary but they are the same. I kind of have an idea how to do this but it 's quite hmm 'messy'. Not sure if I could post my 'pseudo code' here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you wanted, but I made a function that does what you described. There are many ways to make it more efficient, but I'll leave that up to you.

```
t = ['a','b']
x = ['x1','x2','x3','x4']
y = ['y1','y2','y3','y4']

def big_zip(t,x,y):
    a = zip(x, y)
    b = []
    new_list = []
    final = []
    for i in a:
        b.append(i[0]+i[1])
    for i in range(0,len(b)-1,2):
        new_list.append(b[i]+b[i+1])
    for i in range(0,len(t)):
        final.append(t[i]+new_list[i])
    return final

print(big_zip(t,x,y))
```

Comment: No problem! Anytime.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is a bit vague which makes it hard for me to know exactly what you are looking for. But in general you can access the specific element `n` from a Python list `foo` with the code `foo[n]`. Therefore you can build a general list `bar` of length `l` where you also have lists `ham`, `eggs` and `spam` with something like:

```
bar = list()
for i in range(l):
    bar.append(str(ham[i]) + str(eggs[i]) + str(spam[i//2]))
```

Where of course you can access whatever elements of `ham`, `eggs`, and `spam` are best for your purposes.

As a side note, the people in the comments on your post asking you to edit your string format mean that they want your code to be in the form:

```
t = ['a','b']
```

As opposed to:

```
y = ['y1,'y2','y3',y4']
```

Notice how the single quote ' to the right of `y1` and to the left of `y4` is missing in the text for `y`.

Hope this helps! If you ever have issues formatting your questions/answers in Stack Overflow see [this webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for assistance.